# Permisos de grupo para carpeta en linux

Tags: linux, permisos

me gustaría saber si es posible crear dos grupos en Linux y al asignar permisos sobre la misma carpeta, cada grupo tenga permisos distintos.

Ejemplo: Si tengo una carpeta llamada uso_compartido, y dos grupos de usuarios: profesores y alumnos. ¿Cómo podría especificar permisos de lectura al grupo alumnos y de escritura al de profesores? ¿Es posible hacerlo con POSIX?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí, lo puedes hacer con las listas de control de acceso (LCA, o ACL en inglés). Los siguientes ejemplos deben ser ejecutados por root:

```
getfacl directorio/ #muestra las listas de control de acceso de la carpeta  <directorio>
setfacl -d -m grupo:rw directorio/ #agrega permisos de lectura y escritura en la carpeta <directorio> al grupo <grupo>
setfacl -d -m grupo:x directorio/ #agrega permisos de ejecución en la carpeta <directorio> al grupo <grupo>
```

En el caso de directorios, también puedes utilizar la opción `-R` para aplicar recursivamente los permisos.

Puedes ver la documentación detallada del comando con `man setfacl`.

Comment: Gracias, en windows sabia de las ACL pero no en Linux.